# Creating standalone application in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I'm new to GIS but I've already a signifiant experience in development. I work on new project. We're trying to use the power of Qgis to create a GIS tool for our commercial team.

QGis is istalled from OSGeo4W (3.8), Python (3.7) and PyQt (from pip) are installed too.

Correctly set PYTHONPATH :

```
set PYTHONPATH=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python
```

When i try to run my python script (copied from the official documentation "PyQGIS Developper Cookbook"), we've got an error :

```py
from qgis.core import *

# Supply path to qgis install location
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis", True)

# Create a reference to the QgsApplication.  Setting the
# second argument to False disables the GUI.
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)

# Load providers
qgs.initQgis()

# Write your code here to load some layers, use processing
# algorithms, etc.

# Finally, exitQgis() is called to remove the
# provider and layer registries from memory

qgs.exitQgis()
```

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 n’est pas une application Win32 valide.
```

Answer (score 1):

More of a python thing, string file paths need to be like the following:

```
"C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis"
```

OR

```
r"C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis"
```

OR

```
"C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis"
```